# Show that if $\Gamma \models^v \varphi$ then $\Gamma^{\forall} \cup \{ \neg(\varphi^{\forall}) \}$ is not satisfiable

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Assuming $\varphi$ is a formula, $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas, $\varphi^{\forall} = \forall x_1 \forall x_2 \dots \forall x_n \varphi$ where $x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n$ are the free variables in $\varphi$ and $\Gamma^{\forall} = \{ \varphi^{\forall} | \varphi \in \Gamma \}$

Using the facts I know

$M \models \varphi $ if and only if $M \models \varphi^{\forall}$

$M \models \Gamma $ if and only if $M \models \Gamma^{\forall}$

I've tried the following:

If $M \models \Gamma$ then $M \models \varphi$ hence $M \models \varphi^{\forall}$ hence for all valuation $v$ $M,v \models \varphi^{\forall}$ then by $TT_{\neg}$ $M,v \not\models \neg(\varphi^{\forall})$ hence indeed for all valuation $v$ we have $M,v \not\models \Gamma^{\forall} \cup \{ \neg(\varphi^{\forall}) \}$

The second case doesn't seem to work out, if $M \not\models \Gamma$ then i know $M \not\models \Gamma^{\forall}$ but that still doesn't mean there is no valuation $v$ such that $M,v \models \Gamma^{\forall}$.

I will be happy for any help with the second case, or somehow proving it differently.

Comment: What second case ?

Comment: I need to show that for all $M,v$: $M,v \not\models \Gamma^{\forall} \cup \{ \neg (\varphi^{\forall}) \} $. I can show (as described) that if $M \models \Gamma$ then for all $v$ $M,v \not\models \Gamma^{\forall} \cup \{ \neg (\varphi^{\forall}) \} $. but for $M \not\models \Gamma$ i still can't find the proof that for all $v$: $M,v \not\models \Gamma^{\forall} \cup \{ \neg (\varphi^{\forall}) \} $. something doesn't add up.

Comment: But why the case $M \nvDash \Gamma$ ? You want to prove an "iff" ?

Comment: If $M \nvDash \Gamma$, by your known result above you have $M \nvDash \Gamma^{\forall}$ and thus, for sure: $M \nvDash \Gamma^{\forall} \cup \{ \lnot (\varphi^{\forall}) \}$

Comment: Yes, doesn't that means that there exists $v$ such that $M,v \not\models \Gamma^{\forall}$? i.e, it doesn't imply that for all $v$: $M,v \not\models \Gamma^{\forall}$ i.e, doesn't imply unsatisfiability?

Comment: **NO** (regarding also your answer below): to say that for some $v$ we have $M,v \nvDash \Gamma^{\forall}$ means that  (assuming for simplicity that the closure of $\Gamma$ regards only a single variable $x$) there is some $x$-variant $v'$ of $v$ such that $M,v' \nvDash \Gamma$.

Comment: Having said that, I repeat that it is not clear your approach... you are trying to conclude that "for all $v, M,v \nvDash \Gamma^{\forall}$, i.e. implying its unsatisfiability". But you are not asked to prove that $\Gamma^{\forall}$ is unsatisfiable.

Answer (score 1):

$M \not\models \Gamma^{\forall}$ implies there exist $v_0$ such that $M,v_0 \not\models \Gamma^{\forall}$ but $\Gamma^{\forall}$ contains formulas without any free variables hence a different valuation doesn't change anything (no assignment is made). i.e, for all valuations $v(\psi) = v_0(\psi)$ for all $\psi \in \Gamma^{\forall}$ hence for all $v$ we have $M,v \not\models \Gamma^{\forall}$ finishing the proof.

Comment: No! You should check the definition of $M, v_0 \models \varphi$. Even if there is no free variable in $\varphi$, the valuation has an impact.

Comment: I used a theorem stating: If $v_1(x) = v_2(x)$ for all $x \in FV(\varphi)$ then $v_1(\varphi) = v_2(\varphi)$. so if $M,v_0 \not\models \varphi$ then by what i learned it means $v_0(\varphi) = F$ hence by the theorem $v(\varphi) = v_0(\varphi) = F$ for all $v$ since they agree on all the free variables (as there are none) which means $M,v \not\models \Gamma^{\forall}$. I hope this is correct.

Comment: you should check your theorem (stated as you wrote it, it is false)

Comment: What is a counter example?